# RAII idiom for classes with container members

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, raii

I have the following questions about the class described in the code below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class Widget
{
public:
    Widget( int x, int y, int z ) : m_x{x}, m_y{y}, m_z{z} {}

private:
    int m_x, m_y, m_z;
};

class Coord {
public:
    Coord( int x, int y, int z ) : p{x}, q{y}, r{z} { }
    std::tuple<int,int> get_tuple() { return std::make_tuple(p, q); }

    int x() { return p; }
    int y() { return q; }
    int z() { return r; }

private:
    int p, q, r;
};

class Collector
{
public:
    Collector(const std::vector<Coord>& pool) { collect(pool); };

    void collect(const std::vector<Coord>& pool)
    {
        for ( auto v : pool )
        {
            tuple<int,int> key = v.get_tuple();
            auto value = make_shared<Widget>(v.x(), v.y(), v.z());
            m_container.insert(make_pair(key, value));
        }
    }

private:
    map< tuple<int,int>, shared_ptr<Widget> > m_container;
};

int foo()
{
    Coord a{0,0,1};
    Coord b{0,1,0};
    Coord c{1,0,0};
    vector<Coord> pool{a, b, c};
    auto col = std::make_shared<Collector>( pool );
    return 0;
}
```

1. I would like to know if it is RAII compliant. If not, how do I modify its implementation to make it so.
2. I wanted to confirm that the map `Collector::m_container` is stored on the free-store. Are both the tuple-keys and the Widgets both stored on the free-store?
3. Does `foo` leak memory?
4. In what order are the allocated resources destroyed?

Comment: That class doesn't even compile.

Comment: Where does `Collector` get used in `foo`?

Comment: Please fix your code and make it compatible with the question you're asking (whatever that is.)

Comment: @unshul, you can make the question much better by filling in the other gaps in the code, like giving definitions for `InfoPool` and `Widget`, even if they are only placeholder definitions so that it will compile. And filling out the definition of `int foo()`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, every one of your objects is an RAII object, meaning that when it is destroyed it releases any and all acquired resources.
   `Widget` doesn't acquire any resources, so it has nothing to free. Similarly for `Coord`. Generally, standard library templates will be RAII as long as the template parameters are. So `std::shared_ptr<Widget>` is an RAII object, as is `std::map< std::tuple<int, int>, std::shared_ptr<Widget>>`.
2. `m_container` is a structure data member. Formally, if a `Collector` is created on the stack, then `m_container` will be on the stack, and if a `Collector` is created with `new`, then `m_collection` will be on the free-store. However, the standard library definition of `std::map` will generally work by creating "map nodes" using `new`, and the `std::map` object itself will only hold a (fixed) number of pointers to some of those nodes (root objects or such). So as a whole, almost all of the memory it owns is on the free-store as you say, but formally the entity `m_container` can be anywhere in memory.
3. `foo` does not leak any memory, every object that is constructed is an RAII object, and so all the memory is released upon its destruction.
4. You are guaranteed that the five different local variables in `foo` are destroyed in the reverse order of construction. However, at a finer level of detail, it is implementation-defined, for instance, in what order `std::map` nodes are destroyed.

Comment: If only `m_container` were a thing.

Answer (score -1):

1. There are no strict compliance criteria for RAII. Your question is unclear.
2. This can't be answered, because the program doesn't even compile.
3. There are tools that detect memory leaks (or at least some kind of them) for you, learn to use them! Further, you could simply add debug output to the destructors and match them against similar debug output in the constructors. Make sure that you catch *all* constructors though!
4. See answer for question 3.